# Why am I not able to create a calendar event using $cordovaCalendar?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I would like to show an event reminder in the device calendar for my app and am trying to use ngCordova's [`$cordovaCalendar`](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/calendar/) and the [Phonegap Calendar Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin.git) to achieve this. Using the instructions on the ngCordova website I set up ngCordova and installed the plugin, but I am running into the following issue:

[image: TypeError: Cannot read property <code>calendar</code> of undefined]

The error points to the following code in the `ng-cordova.js` file:

```
 $window.plugins.calendar.createEvent(
          defaultOptions.title,
          defaultOptions.location,
          defaultOptions.notes,
          new Date(defaultOptions.startDate),
          new Date(defaultOptions.endDate),
          function (message) {
            d.resolve(message);
          }, function (error) {
            d.reject(error);
          }
        );
```

My controller code:

```
.controller('CalendarCtrl', function ($scope, $cordovaCalendar) {
  $cordovaCalendar.createEvent({
    title: 'Space Race',
    location: 'The Moon',
    notes: 'Bring sandwiches',
    startDate: new Date(2015, 0, 6, 18, 30, 0, 0, 0),
    endDate: new Date(2015, 1, 6, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0)
  }).then(function (result) {
    // success
  }, function (err) {
    // error
  });
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These issues are usually caused by the plugin not being installed correctly or not waiting for all the Cordova plugins to be loaded, I think you may be dealing with the second issue here. Add `$ionicPlatform` as a dependency and try the following:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  $cordovaCalendar.createEvent({
    title: 'Space Race',
    location: 'The Moon',
    notes: 'Bring sandwiches',
    startDate: new Date(2015, 0, 6, 18, 30, 0, 0, 0),
    endDate: new Date(2015, 1, 6, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0)
  }).then(function (result) {
    // success
  }, function (err) {
   // error
  });
});
```

The `$ionicPlatform.ready` ensures that all plugins are loaded before executing any of the defined functions inside of its scope, otherwise you try calling the plugin before it is loaded.

Comment: Thanks . i will try it

Comment: It is working fine .It work on button click with scope function too

Comment: Do you have worked on that plugin too? I have issue on delete Process. First of all it is not deleting as per date range too .like i created 3 event in a day in like 9 am 1 pm and 8 pm .Then i want to only last one then i use start date n end date like this requirement but it is deleting all event of the same day .\

Comment: I have not worked on this plugin, but if you have any further questions or issues, don't hesitate to submit a new question, I am sure we can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Before to provide an answer, I need to know the following:

- You're on an actual device or simulator (not a browser)?
- You've included a reference to cordova.js in your HTML?
- The plugin was actually added and evidence shows up in config.xml?

Comment: * I am on actual device. * yes but no need to include it because at build time it automatically generate . * Plugin added via cmd and showing in plugin list but not showing on config.xml

Comment: The plugin does not have to appear in `config.xml`, even when it is installed. A better way to verify whether a plugin has been installed would be to run `cordova plugins` to list all installed plugins in a project.